# How to highlight an image when a mouse hovers over it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to darken an image when I hover over it with a mouse. The image is a hexagon. I got it to work as a block. How do I make the hightlight appear only over the hexagon image.

```
#container{
position: relative;
width: 687px;
height: 612px;
}
#main_image img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #03CE7B;
}
#nutrition_icon img{
position: absolute;
bottom: 369px;
right: 300px;
}

#nutrition_icon_text
{
position:absolute;    
color:white;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
left:230px;
bottom:435px;
}

#wrap {
position:relative; 
width: 200px;  
height: 145px;
border: 1px solid grey
}

.nutrition_cover {
height: 200px;
width: 180px;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 200px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
display:none;
}

#nutrition_icon:hover .nutrition_cover {
display:block;    
}
```

The JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/konpoly/rf84f6dt/

Comment: It _might_ be possible with [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).  Shameless plug-- I created a library that attempts to simplify this: [CSSInstaglam](https://alexnied.com/cssinstaglam/).  Please note CSS filters don't play nice on pre-Edge IE browsers, so an alternative or fallback might be required.  There may also be a way to do this with shapes or some other CSS technologies-- I wouldn't state with any confidence this is the _only_ approach.

Comment: Alternately, you could just lower the `opacity` of the image in its "unhovered" state, and crank it back to `opacity: 1` when hovered.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/jv8gx8fh/1/)**

```css
    #container{
        position: relative;
        width: 687px;
        height: 612px;
    }
    #main_image img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #03CE7B;
    }
    #nutrition_icon img{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 369px;
        right: 300px;
    }

    #nutrition_icon_text
    {
        position:absolute;    
        color:white;
        font-size:22px;
        font-weight:bold;
        left:230px;
        bottom:435px;
    }

    #wrap {
        position:relative; 
        width: 200px;  
        height: 145px;
        border: 1px solid grey
    }

    .nutrition_cover {
        height: 200px;
        width: 180px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 200px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
        display:none;
    }

    /*#nutrition_icon:hover .nutrition_cover {
        display:block;    
    }*/
    #nutrition_icon img:hover
    {
       -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="main_image">
        <div class="tve_image_caption thrv_wrapper"><span class="tve_image_frame">
        <img src="http://www.cliniquevi.com/templates/clinique-vi/images/alveoles.png" alt="" class="" width="687"             height="612"></span></div>
        </div>
      <div id="nutrition_icon">
        <a href="http://vi.kmmagency.com/services/nutrition/1-2/" class="tveeee_active_hyperlink">
          <img src="http://www.cliniquevi.com/templates/clinique-vi/images/alveole-nutrition.png" alt="">  
        </a>
        <div class="nutrition_cover"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good solution with filters, but, as I noted above, this will not work in pre-Edge Internet Explorer (if that's a dealbreaker).

Answer (score -1):

Highlight an Image on Mouseover
this script makes the image dull and when you put your mouse over it, it comes back to its original size. Is there a possibility to do it the vice versa. Like the image's in normal state but get dim when you put the mouse over it. thank you.

```js
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
<!-- Script courtesy of http://www.web-source.net - Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development
function makevisible(cur,which){
strength=(which==0)? 1 : 0.2
if (cur.style.MozOpacity)
cur.style.MozOpacity=strength
else if (cur.filters)
cur.filters.alpha.opacity=strength*100
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
<img src="yourimage.gif" width="96" height="134" style="filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:1" onMouseover="makevisible(this,0)" onMouseout="makevisible(this,1)">
```